# Nexus 4 Downgrade from 4.4.2 to 4.3 Risks

Tags: nexus-4, downgrade

So I bought my Nexus 4 last month expecting that it'll have a 4.3 OS version. However, my sister accidentally updated the version.

Now, I would like to downgrade my OS version. Following this guide:

http://www.cultofandroid.com/46632/downgrade-nexus-4-to-android-4-3-jelly-bean-from-kitkat/2/

what might be the possible failing scenarios and what am I going to do if that happens.

Comment: I am curious why you want to do this? The bugs mentioned in that article have been addressed in the update from 4.4 to 4.4.2.

Comment: That is not correct. I have 4.4.2 and I am suffering from all the bluetooth related bugs (service crash and bluetooth disconnect/reconnect crazyness). Plus on top of everything the new dialer and few other things quite suck. Big time.
For the first time ever, I am planning to downgrade Android.

Comment: Well that guide seems right, just reflash stock nexus 4 rom and you will be fine. However there is a possibility that you may enter boot loop/softbrick but thats easy to solve and very rare.
I recommend you following this guide it's from google tho : https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images
Sorry for my bad English if I made some mistakes, becouse English is not my mother tongue.

Answer (score 0):

Once you unlock the bootloader, the only major risk you may face is bricking the phone when loading the aosp images of a previous android version.